# Java generics type argument Project is not within bounds of type-variable E

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with java generics that don't allow me to initialize a AVLTree variable.

AVLTree class:

```
public class AVLTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BSTTree<E> {...}
```

BSTTree Class and Node:

```
public class BSTTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {... 
protected static class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Node<E>>{...}}
```

Project Class:

```
public class Project { 

  private String title;

  public Project(String title){
    this.title=title;
  }
 }
```

When I try to do the following:

```
private AVLTree<Project> projectTree;
```

I get an error saying this:

```
type argument Project is not within bounds of type-variable E where E is a type variable:
E extends Comparable<E> declared in class AVLTree
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `Project` is not comparable, what did you expect?

Comment: @Tunaki Can I make it so?

Comment: Of course you can, you can do anything you want :D

Comment: `E extends Comparable<E>` and your class is defined as `class Project`. The compiler is just telling you that the conditions here do not match.

Comment: @Tunaki how can I do it then?

Comment: Hmm, you did it with `Node`, or did you? You just need to implement `Comparable<Project>`.

Comment: @Tunaki But I want to use not just Project, but one more class, I need a generic for that, can't specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class Project implements Comparable<Project> {

  [add CompareTo method]
}
```